# nvl function with in clause

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

I have a problem with NVL function.I can use my in clause properyl but when i add nvl it gives error.

My query like this:

```
SELECT  ci.date, 
 SUM (cid.salary) amount, SUM (cid.slary_gross) gross_amount
    FROM students ci,
         orders cid           
 WHERE 
 ci.id IN  NVL((select id from sysadm.students
 where status = 'IN' AND student_id= 24514 ORDER BY id
 FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY), ci.id )
```

My error:  `01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"`

İf I delete nvl function  and just write like below it is running.How can i use nvl with in clause?

`ci.id IN  (select id from sysadm.students where status = 'IN' AND student_id= 24514 ORDER BY id FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt the `id` is `NULL` in the subquery.  SO I would suggest:

```
with s3 as (
       select s.id
       from sysadm.students s.
       where s.status = 'IN' and s.student_id = 24514
       ORDER BY id
       FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
      )
select . . .
where ci.id in (select id from s3) or
      not exists (select 1 from s3);
```

This checks if your id is in the list -- or that the list is empty.