# Nvl function with multiple row set in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

I have a problem with NVL function in oracle.
If I send periods  variable as null it is working.There is no data in query.I mean NVL function is working properly.
If I send periods variable as for example 10 , it gives error like that

```
single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one
```

This code block does not work because select query  returns more than one row

```
Select .......  FROM students st, orders od  
WHERE  st.id IN NVL((select id from students 
             where student_id = 321
     ORDER BY id desc
          FETCH FIRST periods ROWS ONLY),(od.countNo))
```

I tried to use case when in where block but I cannot use it.Do you have any idea?

Comment: Weren't you already answered, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092374/nvl-function-with-in-clause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nvl function with in clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65092374/nvl-function-with-in-clause)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would get the same error if you changed `IN` to `=`. `IN` can handle sets of multiple rows from a subquery, but `NVL()` and `=` cannot.

If you INSIST on using NVL, change your subquery to return AT MOST 1 row:

```
-- using periods=1
Select .......  FROM students st, orders od  
WHERE  st.id = NVL((select id from students 
                  where student_id = 321
                  ORDER BY id desc
                  FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY),(od.countNo)); 

-- using an aggregate function
Select .......  FROM students st, orders od  
WHERE  st.id = NVL((select max(id) from students 
                  where student_id = 321),(od.countNo));
```

Or if you need multiple rows, rewrite your query to not use NVL:

```
Select .......  FROM students st, orders od  
WHERE EXISTS (select 1 from students 
               where student_id = 321
                 and st.id = students.id
               ORDER BY students.id desc
               FETCH FIRST periods ROWS ONLY)
      OR st.id = od.countNo;
```

A modified version of Gordon's answer from yesterday is another example:

```
with s3 as (
       select id 
       from students 
       where student_id = 321
       ORDER BY id desc
       FETCH FIRST periods ROWS ONLY
      )
Select .......  FROM students st, orders od  
where st.id in (select id from s3) or
      (not exists (select 1 from s3) and st.id = od.countNo);
```